# maxscale rewrite filter with awk

Tags: mysql, awk, mariadb, maxscale, proxysql

The following rewrite rule works as expected:

```
%%
regex_grammar: Awk
case_sensitive: false
ignore_whitespace: true
%
SELECT msg FROM mytable WHERE id = 123
%
SELECT msg FROM mytable WHERE id = sha1(123)
```

My question now is, how can I write this query with placeholder in regex_grammer: Awk. If I knew that, I would have a breakthrough for the next problem. My actual goal is to rewrite the following query:

```
Input:
SELECT msg FROM mytable WHERE id IN (123,456,769)

Output:
SELECT msg FROM mytable WHERE id IN (sha1(123),sha1(456),sha1(769))
```

I assume that this only works with regex_grammar Awk and not with Native. Am I right?

This is the only documentation that I found: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-2208-rewrite-filter/

I also accept other suggestions or tools! Maxscale looked the most promising solution to me.

Comment: Is the number of values in the `IN` clause constant or does it change for every query? If it does change, the problem would require a repeating regex of some sorts for the values.

Comment: The number of id's cannot be predicted, it can vary depending on the query.

And you spotted the exact problem, I need to loop over the values. On the console this is not a problem:

echo "123,456,789" | awk '{a=split($0, ff, ","); n=""; for (i in ff) {n=n"sha1("ff[i]"),"}; gsub(",$" , "", n); print n}'

But I don't know how to write (syntax) that in maxscale ;)

Comment: You could try using the `luafilter` from the `maxscale-experimental` package. You can program the replacement to be done with Lua which should allow you to do pretty much anything you want. Another alternative is to use the `regexfilter` that always uses PCRE2 patterns which support recursion and other advanced regular expression features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of replacement you're doing requires repeated substitutions with no fixed amount of values. The rewrite filter is intended for simpler use-cases where the patterns are fixed and do not require complex matching.

However, this can still be done with the `regexfilter` in MaxScale that allows more free-form use of regular expressions. The following regexfilter configuration should handle simple values in an `IN` list and wrap them in a `SHA1` function call.

```
[regex]
type=filter
module=regexfilter
match=/(?i)(IN\s+\(|,)\s*([^,]+)\s*/
replace=$1 SHA1($2)
```

Here's the [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Xxe0Vu/2) page I used to test it.

Note that this won't work with strings with embedded commas in them which means it's not really an universal solution.

Comment: Thanks @markusjm, never thought that someone could answer my question. Now I can get down to the miragtion. Works exactly as intended